# SQL Server - How to Update Multiple Columns/Conditions and Ignore Certain Columns in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables and would like to update table t in SQL Server 2008:

table w:

```
+--------+----+------+------+------+
| DataID | AFD|  PSD |  PFD | ASD  |    
+--------+----+------+------+------+
|      1 | B  | E    | A    |      |  
|      2 | I  |      | B    |  W   |      
|      3 |    |      | Y    |  D   |   
|      4 |    | Q    |      |  T   |     
|      5 | T  | E    | D    |  T   | 
+--------+----+------+------+------+
```

table t:

```
+--------+----+------+------+------+
| DataID | AFD|  PSD |  PFD | ASD  |    
+--------+----+------+------+------+
|      1 | A  | E    |      |  Z   |  
|      2 | B  | F    | Y    |      |      
|      3 | C  | G    | G    |  T   |   
|      4 | B  | E    |      |      |     
|      5 | T  | G    | Y    |  Z   | 
+--------+----+------+------+------+
```

Question/Attempt: How to update table t checking for multiple conditions?

Note: NULL is text not an empty column.

```
update t
SET t.ACTFINISHDATE = GETDATE()
,t.PROJSTARTDATE = 
(CASE 2
WHEN t.PROJSTARTDATE = 'NULL' THEN t.PROJSTARTDATE = w.PROJSTARTDATE
WHEN w.PROJSTARTDATE = 'NULL' THEN GETDATE()
ELSE GETDATE()
END)
,t.PROJFINISHDATE =
(CASE 3
WHEN t.PROJFINISHDATE = 'NULL' THEN t.PROJFINISHDATE = w.PROJFINISHDATE
WHEN w.PROJFINISHDATE = 'NULL' THEN GETDATE()
ELSE GETDATE()
END)
,t.ACTSTARTDATE =
(CASE 3
WHEN t.ACTSTARTDATE = 'NULL' THEN t.ACTSTARTDATE = w.ACTSTARTDATE
WHEN w.ACTSTARTDATE = 'NULL' THEN GETDATE()
ELSE GETDATE()
END)

FROM w
  JOIN t ON w.DataID = t.DataID
WHERE   ( ( cold IN ( 'A', 'B' ) 
       AND cols IN ( 'E', 'F' ) ) 
      OR ( cold = 'C' 
           AND cols = 'G' ) )
```

Question 2: How do I ignore update on C data in cold and F data in cols (so basically, ignore any data where Cold = C AND ColS = F)

table t with additional columns:

```
+--------+-----+-------+
| DataID | Cold|  ColS |    
+--------+-----+-------+
|      1 | A   | E     | 
|      2 | B   | G     |      
|      3 | A   | G     |  
|      4 | B   | E     |   
|      5 | C   | F     |
|      6 | C   | F     |
+--------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `PROJSTARTDATE`.

Comment: datetime, all the fields are datetime except the ID column

Comment: Then you can never store **text** `NULL` in datetime field

Comment: Each columns have datetime and NULL values. The NULL values are in there because an update script was run to replaced all empty dates with NULL, so they is no empty values. I want to override the NULL values of table t based on the case statement.

Comment: you have to exactly explain,what do you want to ignore ?on which value you want to ignore.give lil explanation.

Comment: i think your query is already doing that.you won't get any record where Cold = C AND ColS = F.i think you should just put on extra bracket.Put the same query for select and test it.  ( ( cold IN ( 'A', 'B' ) 
       AND cols IN ( 'E', 'F' ) )
      OR ( (cold = 'C') AND (cols = 'G') ) )

Comment: Currently the query updates the table t using the case statements to get the dates. In the third table in my original post, I only want it to update IF Cold = A,B AND ColS = G,E. In other words it is updating the dates when Cold = C AND ColS = F. I don't know how to ignore these to not update (they are needed in the where clause otherwise the results that come back are wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `join` is working, then your `case` statements should be changed as follows:

```
update t
set t.ACTFINISHDATE = GETDATE(),
    t.PROJSTARTDATE = 
        CASE WHEN t.PROJSTARTDATE = 'NULL' THEN w.PROJSTARTDATE
        ELSE GETDATE()
        END,
    t.PROJFINISHDATE =
        CASE WHEN t.PROJFINISHDATE = 'NULL' THEN w.PROJFINISHDATE
        ELSE GETDATE()
        END,
    t.ACTSTARTDATE =
        CASE WHEN t.ACTSTARTDATE = 'NULL' THEN w.ACTSTARTDATE
        ELSE GETDATE()
        END
FROM w
    LEFT JOIN T ON..
WHERE ....
```

You don't see many updates to `outer joins` though...

Comment: lil correction needed.if for example w.PROJSTARTDATE ='NULL' then getdate().second correction.getdate() will throw error because datatype are not datetime.it must be varchar

Comment: @KumarHarsh yes, the above query gets conversion failed when converting date from character string error.  Could this be fixed by converting the column to varchar?

Comment: @AlkippeNikephoros , yup convert getdate() to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are `NULL` and not `'NULL'` as in the example, you can do this:

```
update t
SET t.ACTFINISHDATE  = GETDATE()
   ,t.PROJSTARTDATE  = COALESCE(t.PROJSTARTDATE,  w.PROJSTARTDATE,  GETDATE())
   ,t.PROJFINISHDATE = COALESCE(t.PROJFINISHDATE, w.PROJFINISHDATE, GETDATE())
   ,t.ACTSTARTDATE   = COALESCE(t.ACTSTARTDATE,   w.ACTSTARTDATE,   GETDATE())
 ....
```